# Issues with dependencies, modules. How do I properly reference this library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm confused by something. I'm working on an Android app with two modules.  Here's my project structure

```
MyProject
   app
      libs
         abc.jar
      src
      etc...
   importedProject
      libs
      src
      etc...
      build.gradle
   build.gradle
```

If I right click on abc.jar, and choose `Add as Library...`, a dialog comes up asking me which module to add to with the options `app` and `importedProject`.

If I select `importedProject`, it adds a dependency to importedProject's build.gradle file.. but it uses the full path to the file on my hard drive.

```
compile files('C:/Users/my.name/workspace/MyProject/app/libs/abc.jar')
```

I'm very confused why it's using a full local path rather than relative. Android Studio even warns me not to do this, yet it does it for me.

I've tried these and none work:

```
compile files('app/libs/abc.jar')
compile files('MyProject/app/libs/abc.jar')
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?  Thank you

**EDIT**:

Got it to work using:

```
compile files('../app/libs/abc.jar')
```

However, I've read that using relative paths is a bad idea.  Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Paths in a Gradle build file are typically relative to the location of the build file. In this case you want the path to be relative to the *root* project.

```
compile files("${rootProject.projectDir}/app/libs/abc.jar")
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  It doesn't seem to be working though.  I changed from `"../app/libs/abc.jar"` to `"${rootProject.projectDir}/app/libs/abc.jar"` and it isn't catching it.

Comment: Is this a proper multi-project build. Can you post the contents of your *settings.gradle* file?